# Python selenium click a button without id

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

i have this code

```
<a href="#" class="button expanded vote" style="background: rgb(51, 204, 102) none repeat scroll 0% 0%; border-radius: 5px;" onclick="Poll.sendAnswer("Programn2015","Answer1","Answer2")">Vote</a>
```

what could i do? there are other buttons on the page with the same class etc, the only variables are

```
"Answer1","Answer2"
```

Comment: *"what could i do?"*... What did you try?

Comment: And what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Post the relevant HTML or a link to the page

Comment: Pleas share with few more html with parent tags or sibiling tags of it.

Answer (score 0):

To click on the link with text as **Vote** you can use either of the following solutions:

- `css_selector`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.button.expanded.vote[onclick*='Answer1'][onclick*='Answer2']").click()
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='button expanded vote' and contains(.,'Vote')][contains(@onclick,'Answer1') and contains(@onclick,'Answer2')]").click()
  ```

---

### Update

Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable* as follows:

- `css_selector`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.button.expanded.vote[onclick*='Answer1'][onclick*='Answer2']"))).click()
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='button expanded vote' and contains(.,'Vote')][contains(@onclick,'Answer1') and contains(@onclick,'Answer2')]"))).click()
  ```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"a.button.expanded.vote[onclick*='Answer1'][onclick*='Answer2']"}
  (Session info: chrome=70.0.3538.67)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=69.0.3497.106 (857b284701ddf7bef0f14fa76416cf7ca786b411),platform=Linux 4.15.0-36-generic x86_64)

Comment: if i copy xpath with the firefox editor i get " //*[@id="sondaggi"]/div/div[24]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/a " but doing chrome.find_element_by_xpath(' //*[@id="sondaggi"]/div/div[24]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/a').click() it doesn't find it in the page

Comment: @MimmoBrescia Checkout my updated answer and let me know the status

Comment: hi, i get this error with both " File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium-2.53.6-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: "